# Marginal densities of a random vector with piecewise joint density

Tags: probability

Let $\left(X,Y \right)$ a random vector with joint density

$f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = 
\begin{cases} 
 kx,  & 0\leq x\leq y\leq 1 \newline\newline ky, & 0\leq y<x\leq 1 
\end{cases}$

(a) Find $k$.

(b) Find the marginal densities of $X$ and $Y$.

I've found that

$\displaystyle \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)\ dx\ dy=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{y} kx \ dx\right)\ dy + \int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{x} ky\ dy\right)\ dx=\frac{k}{6} + \frac{k}{6}=\frac{k}{3}$

and so, $k=3$ is necessarily for having a joint density.

Now, for the second point I've obtained

$f_{X}(x) = (3x-\frac{3}{2}x^2)\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}(x)$

and

$f_{Y}(y) = (3y-\frac{3}{2}y^2)\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}(y) $

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

a) is wrong

$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}f(x, y)dxdy = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y}f(x,y)dxdy+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{1}f(x,y)dxdy $

Comment: Isn't it equivalent to mine?

Comment: No, moreover I got different value of k. 

In b) use

$f_{X}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)dy=\int_{0}^{x}f(x,y)dy+\int_{x}^{1}f(x,y)dy$

Comment: Ok, I try to recalculate the integral

Comment: Ok, so the marginal densities are not piecewise ?

Comment: After your edit, you still wrongly calculated integrals in a).

Comment: How does it come to you?

Comment: Expand your calculations, so you could find a mistake by your own.

Comment: Hi, errors fixed!

Comment: No, they are not fixed. Unfortunately you need to focus on proper integration.

Comment: Hi, it seems right to me now, the support of the joint density is the union of two triangles that form a square of side 1 and I integrate the corresponding function on each triangle and then I add the two integrals and I obtain that result. If you don't agree, suggest your result :)

Comment: I switched the two integrals compared to what you suggested but it is equivalent for the Fubini -Tonelli theorem...